# How to make mouse scrolling in Excel behave like Page Up/Page Down

Tags: microsoft-excel, mouse, scrolling

In Excel when I press <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> it always scrolls *no more than 1 page* and *jumps exactly to the next row that was not displayed fully* (if the current row isn't taller than the window, of course). This is very useful as it prevents me from ever missing a row; for example when I want to have a quick check for something in every row I can just press <kbd>Page Down</kbd> repeatedly and scan the whole page or column.

However when I scroll using the mouse, things are different. It always scrolls exactly the number of rows equal to the number of lines set in Windows' vertical scrolling setting for the mouse, as seen below:

[image: screenshot of vertical scrolling mouse options]

This is annoying as it skips many rows when the current 3 rows' total height is too tall to fit in the window. It also makes scrolling speed vary greatly when the rows' heights vary too much.

**Is there any way to make the mouse scroll the screen by a page per notch of the scroll button?**

Comment: What happens if you select `One screen at a time` instead of `The following number of lines at a time` in the above Vertical Scrolling  dialog?

Comment: Depending on what mouse you have, vendor-provided software may allow you to define app-specific behaviors. SetPoint can do that for Logitech mice.

Comment: @David the problem with that option is that everything else is also scrolled one page at a time. Actually I want any document to scroll the distance exactly 3 times the height of a line/row but that's not possible with Excel so I want it to scroll 1 page for Excel alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this autohotkey script

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
WheelUp::Send {PgUp}
WheelDown::Send {PgDn}
```